# UIImageView scrolls according to UiScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am using indicator with image view, and i am adding this image view to scrollview,whenever i scroll up image view is not in center.

```
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initwithframe:CGRectmake(130,222,60,60)];
    imageView.animationImages = [LYTThemeCreator getIndicatorGifImagesArray];
    imageView.animationDuration = 2.5;
    imageView.center = _UIScrollView.center;
    [_UIScrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add  self. _UIScrollView.contentSize of scrollview

Comment: did you use auto layout or auto resize mask?

Comment: Auto resize mask @Shadowfiend

Comment: what's the frame of your scroll view and what's its content size

Comment: use for image and scroll view _UIScrollView.autoresizingMask =UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

Comment: _uiscrollView.frame = cgrect(0,0,320,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)          
_uiscrollView.Contentsize = cgsize(320,1000);
@Shadowfiend

Comment: what do you mean by whenever i scroll up image view is not in center, vertical center or horizontal center? @swe

Comment: It should be in horizontal center,middle of the screen.